# why did I get HTTP Status 404, when I use withformat to render results as json in grails?

Tags: json, url, grails, http-status-code-404, render

I'm writing a grails app. I use withFormat to render the result. Here is the code:

```
class TestController{
   def index(){
      def result = ["a":"1"]
      withFormat {
         json{ render result as JSON }
         xml{ render result as XML}
      }
   }
}
```

And I use the url `.../test` and `.../test/index.json`
and `.../test/index` 
to test this. It gave me a `HTTP Status 404` error and told me that `the requested resource is not available.`
I'm not sure why this happened.

Comment: At a guess I'd say the URL isn't pointing at the file. The three leading `.` might be the cause. Try `../test`. (Just 2 `.`)

Comment: Which version of Grails do you use? It works for me as expected with the above (exactly your) controller implementation in 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is the request isn't being processed in any of the closures of you withFormat block. Since you don't have a fall back render, you're getting a 404 because there probably isn't an index.gsp. You should debug the action and find out how the request is being processed.